# What is a half-list template in Car app for Android?

Tags: android, android-auto, android-automotive

What is a half-list template in Car app for Android? The description [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/model/Row.Builder#addAction(androidx.car.app.model.Action)) says that the addAction cannot be used on half-list template. Could someone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

Half-list is when the list of items does not take up the full screen space available. For example, the `ItemList` for a `PlaceListMapTemplate` only takes up part of the screen so that the map is still visible. The same goes for other templates such as the `PlaceListNavigationTemplate`, `RoutePreviewNavigationTemplate`, and the `MapTemplate` when used with an `ItemList`.